# bootstrap dropdown "open" event in angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm trying to create a directive which opens a bootstrap dropdown on click and closes it when the mouse leaves. 
 the dropdown directive code:

```
import {Directive, HostBinding, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[rbDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.open') get opened() {
    return this.isOpen;
  }
  @HostListener('click') open(){
    this.isOpen = true;
  }
  @HostListener('mouseleave') close(){
    this.isOpen = false;
  }

  private isOpen = false;

}
```

Then, in the dropdown li item, I use this directive:

```
<li class="dropdown" rbdropdown>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">User <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Otg=her</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

But it's not working...

Comment: Hey. I'm getting same problem even directive name is same there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, stupid problem...the IDE changed the directive name in the li element and I didn't notice it